# Can we deduce that $t=v$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f,g:ℝ²→ℝ$ two functions with continuous partial derivatives $f_{x}, f_{y}, g_{x}$ and $g_{y}$.

Generally, we have $t≠v$ since $f≠g$. Assume now that $f_{x}=g_{y}$ and $f_{y}=-g_{x}$. My question is: Can we deduce that $t=v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I think you have a sign switched in the equations following "Applying the theorem to $f$ and $g$...")

The theorem only states that such points *exist*, and does not define them uniquely. For instance, if $f = g = 1 + x + y$, then all of the partial derivatives are equal to $1$, and for **any** $\alpha,\beta,\mu,\rho,\gamma,\xi,\delta,\lambda$, it is true that

$$
f(\alpha,\beta) - f(\mu,\rho) = \alpha + \beta - \mu - \rho \\
 = (\alpha - \mu) + (\beta - \rho) = f_x(\gamma,\xi)(\alpha - \mu) + f_y(\gamma,\xi)(\beta - \rho)
$$

and similarly for $g$.

Comment: (I think you have a sign switched in the equations following "Applying the theorem to $f$ and $g$.. Can you elaborate.

Comment: Multiply either side of those equations by $-1$ to get the correct statement. E.g. either the way I have it written in my answer above, or $f(\mu,\rho) - f(\alpha,\beta) = f_x(\gamma,\xi)(\mu - \alpha) + f_y(\gamma,\xi)(\rho,\beta)$